# How to allocate string including comma to control.Name property in wpf

Tags: wpf, properties, controls

```
Image im=new Image();
string ii="123456789";
im.Name=ii;
```

It's ok

but

```
Image im=new Image();
string ii="123.456.789";
im.Name=ii;
```

It throw exception.  Why is it denied to allocate comma "." to control Name property?

Comment: That's *not* a comma, it's a full stop and it's not allowed because the full stop is used to separate the name from it's members (properties/methods/etc.) eg. SomeName.SomeProperty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote is probably not what you want. As MDoobie said, there are restrictions on what the value of Name can be. The Image class is inheriting the Name property from its immediate parent class, "System.Windows.FrameworkElement." Follow MDoobie's "msdn" link to see what the purpose of that Name attribute is. Near the end of the Remarks you will see a link that will lead you to the specific information about Name restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, Names have some restrictions (for instance it cannot contains dots).
"The string values used for Name have some restrictions, as imposed by the underlying x:Name Directive defined by the XAML specification. Most notably, a Name must start with a letter or the underscore character (_), and must contain only letters, digits, or underscores. " (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx))